# 404 not Found with WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I study a WebSocket techology through this resource using Eclipse and GlassFish:
[enter link description here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#section4)

It works fine without any errors but when I try to get a home page on localhost:8080/WebsocketHome (with beginnig http://) I get 404 Not Found.
It might be the mapping problem but I actually don't know what I must change or do.
Here are screen shot of a project build and error page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xYcP.png)

Comment: If you go to http://localhost:4848 you will reach the GlassFish admin console. On the left, there will be a link called `Applications`. You can click that to see your application and its name. There should also be a `Launch` link in the table next to your application which should give you the correct URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for the issue. When I follow the links I get an error page says about the invalid address.